# How to give different layouts for different resolutions in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I used a layout for different resolutions but it did not look good. So I want to know how to make different layouts for different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Mr Aks, you are supposed to create different folders for each resolution, in the resources' folder. The location will be something like this, `C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\Appname\app\src\main\res`. The folder names you can keep will be:

- layout (layout for normal screen size)
- layout-small (layout for small screen size)
- layout-large (layout for large screen size)
- layout-xlarge (layout for extra large screen size).

If you need more help than you can write more questions, I will answer them.